# SpringData Elasticsearch NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using SpringData to connect my application to Elastic search local instance. When I do a regular `curl` to get ES info, it works fine, but I am unable to connect to it from Springboot application.
Elasticsearch local version `./elasticsearch -V => Version: 7.6.0`
SpringData Elastic search version `3.1.11`

```
> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state?pretty'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "1_8HMIK5QDug_xH80VZLgQ",
  "version" : 54,
  "state_uuid" : "YEe1FSwfRUuw0uw-T69fJQ",
  "master_node" : "Nbktx7KrREetbyfL7v0Fog",
  "blocks" : { },
  "nodes" : {
    "Nbktx7KrREetbyfL7v0Fog" : {
      "name" : "k***-macOS",
      "ephemeral_id" : "pqMw40oPTUmBoHsyTAz9cg",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9301",
      "attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "17179869184",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20"
      }
    }
  },
```

```
    @Value("$ELASTIC_HOST")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("$ELASTIC_PORT")
    private String EsPort;

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
    @Bean
    public Client elasticsearchClient() throws UnknownHostException {


        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress( new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), Integer.valueOf(EsPort));
        return client;
    }
```

Tried all the above ways to get a host and port **ALSO TRIED WITH 9300** but still no luck. Also, my `elasticsearch.yml` is the default file and did not add any explicit host or ports.

`Docker-compose`

```
version: '3'
services:
  elastic:
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'xx'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'xx'
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT_NAME: "dev"
      REGION_NAME: "local"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xx"
      POSTGRES_USER: "xx"
      POSTGRES_HOST: "db"
      ELASTIC_HOST: "elastic"
      ELASTIC_PORT: "9200"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - elastic
```

`ERROR:`

```
"failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{JjFZc4y-RBCYbdELAsgaAQ}{elastic}{172.20.0.2:9200}]"}
```

`It works if I change this to`

```
environment:
      ENVIRONMENT_NAME: "dev"
      REGION_NAME: "local"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxx"
      POSTGRES_USER: "xx"
      POSTGRES_HOST: "db"
      ELASTIC_HOST: "elastic"
      ELASTIC_PORT: "9300" --> this is changed from 9200
```

```
client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9201));
```

No, idea why !!

Comment: trasport client is deprecated in favour of high level rest client refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html , also you are giving port 9200, instead of 9300, can u change that and let me know?

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my comment

Comment: I did that and no luck. The problem is that my application is running on a docker container and "localhost" is referred to docker's localhost. I don't see the error when I moved my elastic to docker as well.

Comment: wow, you should have told about this earlier in your question :), anyway can you provide dockerfile or configuration of your application?

Comment: It didn't completely solve my problem, I am still trying to figure out the right configurations to pass. I've added my docker-compose in the post and I am getting the same exception, with updated elasticsearchClient() method

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.11 is built with Elasticsearch client libraries in version 6.2.2. So even if you manage to get a connection to the cluster, the chances are very high, that the client and the cluster can't communicate properly.

As for the setup of the connection: You should add the name of the cluster you want to connect to into the settings:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
            .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
            .build();
```